# How to restrict sending multiple images in one message from a user to a telegram bot?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm making a telegram bot in Python that edits an image.

Tell me how to make it so that the user can send only one image in a message? But how can you control the number of images in a message from a user via the API?

I read the TelegramAPI documentation, but didn't find anything on this topic. It seems to me that you cannot prevent a user from sending multiple images in one message. But then I would like the bot to see an attempt to send it several photos at a time and report this to the user.

Thanks for the answer :-)

Comment: That's right, you cannot block user to send multiple photos but you can recognize if they sent multiple photos or not, if they do then the message object will have media_group_id attribute and then you can act accordingly

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

How about comparing the files' extensions each time a user sends a message? For instance, the message could have a `.png` or `.jpg` suffix and there could be a limitation for their number of usage.

Could be useful to check the message's content, first.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! Solved the problem with the help of Aditya Yadav's comment. Solution below:

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
if not message.media_group_id:
def function(message):
...
else:
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Please send only one image!")